# Way to close developer panel

Tags: google-chrome

The page https://developers.google.com/web/tools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts explains that you can open the Developer Panel with Control + Shift + C (Linux). Is there a way to CLOSE the Developer Panel using a keyboard shortcut?

I could not find one in the doc, but it is kind of strange that you could open but not close the panel without the mouse.

Comment: Can't you use Control + Shift + I ? Or does that not fit your needs? Technically Control + Shift + C just enables the element picker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can open and close Chrome's Developer Panel panel with the `F12` key or using `Ctrl + Shift + I` (At least for windows, but I guess it will be the same for Linux)